# How do I aggregate over a continuous sequence of events occurring cyclically?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table:

| indication | num |
| --- | --- |
| stop | 6 |
| stop | 2 |
| start | 3 |
| start | 8 |
| stop | 7 |
| stop | 3 |
| stop | 2 |
| start | 8 |
| start | 3 |

Solution Output:

| indication | sum_values |
| --- | --- |
| stop | 8 |
| start | 11 |
| stop | 12 |
| start | 11 |

```
WITH stop_start(indication, num) AS (
VALUES 
('stop' , 6),
('stop' , 2),
('start' , 3),
('start' , 8),
('stop' , 7),
('stop' , 3),
('stop' , 2),
('start' , 8),
('start' , 3)
)

SELECT * FROM stop_start;
```

Comment: Please explain the logic.  And if you are assuming an ordering of the rows, then SQL requires a column to contain the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gap-and-islands problem -- assuming you have a column that specifies the ordering.  Probably the simplest solution is to use the difference of row numbers to identify the groups:

```
select indication, sum(num)
from (select ss.*,
             row_number() over (partition by indication order by ?) as seqnum_2,
             row_number() over (order by ?) as seqnum
      from stop_start ss
     ) ss
group by indication, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9e756247fe88bea5dfb621d4f45a1b6a) is a db<>fiddling.